# "Parent module not loaded, cannot perform relative import" with textract package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import, git-clone

As I'm working on Windows (ouch..), I wasn't able to install [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package correctly.

I still tried to clone a git repository from here : https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract

I cloned it in the "site-packages" directory of Python 3, and I tried to run a basic code on one of my pdf files just to check if it was working :

```
from textract.textract import process
text = process('marqueurs_cadratifs.pdf')
```

My PDF file is in the main directory of the projet.

When I run it, I'm getting this error :

```
Parent module 'textract.parsers' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I've seen several issues where the error was the same but it was never matching my specific case and it couldn't help...

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Can it be, that you put it one directory too deep? i.e. `.../site-packages/textract/textract/...` whereas `.../site-packages/textract/...` would be the case. You don't want the complete repo in there but only the `textract` directory of it. (or use the described `setup.py`-install)

Comment: @DaveJ thanks, it solved my problem ! unfortunately i get some other errors but anyway thanks for helping !